# Styling a declared function using styled-components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, styled-components

I'm trying to style a function using tailwind-styled-components and it keeps throwing the error that the function has already been defined. Since I'm using NextJS for this, I am declaring a function that renders my logo in an index file in the assets folder.

```
import Image from next/image

export const Logo = () => {
        return <Image src={logo} alt='Logo' />
    }
```

What I would like is to style the logo in different ways when rendering it on different pages. This applies more to the dimensions of the image and probably opacity. This is what I'm doing to style it

```
const Logo = tw.img`
    h-28
`
```

This approach throws the error "Parsing error: Identifier 'UberLogo' has already been declared."
How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you are going to want to pass the function into parentheses like this

```jsx
const StyledLogo = tw(Logo)`
  h-28
`
```

after doing so `StyledLogo` will be a styled constant of `Logo()` that can be used just like the original function, just styled.

Comment: Thank you for your insight. I am actually doing that and I still can't get it to work. I seem to only pass the props that are defined in the functions and not passed as classes in the tw component

Comment: can i ask what will go inside of the function, just to understand why you're trying to do exactly...

Comment: I will have a few of these functions, just for loading images. Take the logo function, for example, I just want to make a function that will only return the logo, then proceed to style it differently as per my wishes on different pages. It's pretty much exactly as I wrote down in the original post with no additions.